# React: How to dynamically append child components of differing types into a parent component?

Tags: javascript, list, reactjs, dynamic, components

I am trying to set the contents of a component `<ParentComponent/>` dynamically by appending various child components `<ChildComponen1/>, <ChildComponen3/>, <ChildComponen3/>` according to the props values passed to the `<ParentComponent/>`. The parent component is a list and the child components are list items with varying content (css, html)

Below I have detailed an approach that I think would be appropriate for the situation however If you have an alternative (more efficient) method of achieving the specified goal of dynamically populating a parent component with various different child components, your insight would be most appreciated.
Thanks

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component{
    render(){
       return(

            <ComponentSwitch type="ChildComponen1"/>  
            <ComponentSwitch type="ChildComponen2"/>
      )
    }
}


class ComponentSwitch extends React.Component{
    render(){
          return(
            //How would I most effectively create a switch here?
          )
    }
}

...child components omitted for brevity
```

What would be the most effective and efficient way to achieve this function?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write some Javascript...
Many possibilities here, for example:

```
class ComponentSwitch extends React.Component {
  renderA() {
    return (
      <div>
        ... lot of child components here
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.a) {
      return this.renderA();
    }

    return <B />;
  }
}
```

Or use `switch` statement and return component to render. Whatever you do

```
class ComponentSwitch extends React.Component {
  render() {
    switch (this.props.component) {
      case 'a':
        return <A />;

      case 'b':
        return <B />;

      default:
        return <C />;
    }
  }
}
```

Do whatever JS allows you to do :)

Comment: Thanks, you're the best!

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer the issue I understood, that I'm not sure is your real problem but here it goes.

First make your `type` parameter as the real `Class` you want it to be represented by.

```
import ChildComponent1 from './ChildComponent1.jsx';
import ChildComponent2 from './ChildComponent2.jsx';

class ParentComponent extends React.Component{
  render(){
     return(
        <ComponentSwitch type={ChildComponen1} name='John'/>  
        <ComponentSwitch type={ChildComponen2} name='Doe'/>
      )
  }
}
```

Then extract the `type` from the `props`, and pass the rest of the `props` for the child `Component`.

```
class ComponentSwitch extends React.Component{
    render(){
      const {
        type: Component,
        ...props,
      } = this.props;

      // props will now have 'name' and other props ready for the child component
      return <Component {...props} />;
    }
}
```